# After dropping HDD and booting it up, if it works is there any long term damage?

Tags: hard-drive, boot

I've just dropped my macbook pro laptop off a desk; when I picked it up the screen was frozen and when I held down the power button I got the close down dialog and it closed.

I've now rebooted it, and it seems to be working fine (I'm writing this post on it now), this being so could there be any long term damage to the HDD or if it boots fine will it be as ok as it was before the drop?

Answer (score 1):

**Always have back ups in 2 locations that are remote from your current location. Even if everything is fine, you aren't safe without backups. If you don't have a back up, take one right NOW.**

**If your drive is making odd sounds - any grinding/squealing then power it off and refer to an expert. The longer you run it in this state the less likely you are to be able to rescue any data**

As it froze I'm presuming the free fall detection kicked in (details [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201666)) however if it's a SSD then I'm unsure why it crashed but you should still try to make sure *all* the storage is ok.

The problem is while the system might be working, there maybe damage to the disk which *hasn't yet shown up*, either because you've not touched the physical part of the disk which got damaged, or because something has come loose within the hdd enclosure and it's just a matter of time until it gets stuck and things go bad very fast.

Apple's built in disk utility is very useful for verifying the data on the disk, and it uses the reliable fsck to do so however it won't verify the physical health of the disk itself. For this you might want to use suggestions in the answers on [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5424/what-is-the-best-free-hard-drive-diagnostics-app-for-mac-os-x).

Comment: Thanks, just to confirm its an HDD not an SSD

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you probably dodged a bullet, but if you're still paranoid, you could always make a disk image  (it's a good idea to do that on a regular basis anyway).  That way, if a problem develops, you could restore the image to a new hard drive.